# extract content of large lists through a loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

i have about 30 padronized large list and i want to extract elements that are organized in the same way in all of them.

```
> df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "Non-histaminic angioedema"
> df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "Rare urticaria"
> df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[3]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "Rare allergic respiratory disease"
```

i want a loop to extract all these info to a data.frame. I tried to use `lapply`, but i'm having trouble with the right function to use.

i never used the apply family, so i would be very grateful with some tips

-----------------edit

```
str(df)

$ Availability:List of 1
  ..$ Licence:List of 3
  .. ..$ FullName       :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International"
  .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. ..$ ShortIdentifier: chr "CC-BY-4.0"
  .. ..$ LegalCode      : chr "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode"
 $ DisorderList:List of 2
  ..$ Disorder:List of 5
  .. ..$ OrphaNumber           : chr "98050"
  .. ..$ ExpertLink            :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ text  : chr "http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/OC_Exp.php?lng=en&Expert=98050"
  .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. ..$ Name                  :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Rare allergic disease"
  .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. ..$ ClassificationNodeList:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ ClassificationNode:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ ClassificationNodeChildList:List of 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ ClassificationNode:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Disorder                   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ OrphaNumber: chr "658"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ExpertLink :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/OC_Exp.php?lng=en&Expert=658"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Name       :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Non-histaminic angioedema"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs     : Named chr "8618"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ClassificationNodeChildList:List of 3
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ClassificationNode:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Disorder                   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ OrphaNumber: chr "91378"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ExpertLink :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/OC_Exp.php?lng=en&Expert=91378"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Name       :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Hereditary angioedema"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs     : Named chr "12136"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ClassificationNodeChildList:List of 3
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ClassificationNode:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Disorder                   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ OrphaNumber: chr "528623"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ ExpertLink :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/OC_Exp.php?lng=en&Expert=528623"
```

this represents the structure of one of my lists, and i want to extract only what is contained in

```
    df$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text
```

as you can see, this structure repeats along the file (in this case, twice, because I paste only a small part)

```
head(df$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList[1]$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text)

[1] "Non-histaminic angioedema"

head(df$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList[2]$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text)

[1] "Hereditary angioedema"
```

I want to extract these information in each of the 30 lists I have

Comment: Are you only interested in the `6th` nested list element, We can use `sapply(1:30, function(i) df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[i]][[1]][[3]][[1]])`

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? Based on that, show expected output also.

Comment: the 6th element specifies diferent topics and modificates the final element. I was clear?

Comment: @markus i will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the index of the 6th nested list and extract that component (assuming all other index are constant)

```
sapply(1:30, function(i) df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[i]][[1]][[3]][[1]])
```

It is better to check the `length` of the `list` to make this more dynamic

```
l1 <- length(df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[i]])
sapply(seq_len(l1), function(i) df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[i]][[1]][[3]][[1]])
```

Or if we use the OP's updated post with names

```
sapply(seq_len(l1), function(i) 
      df$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList[i]$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) df[[2]][[1]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[i]][[1]][[2]][[1]])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Or with `pluck`

```
library(purrr)
map(1:3, ~ pluck(df, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, .x, 1, 2, 1))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

#### data

```
df <- replicate(3, replicate(2, replicate(4, replicate(4, replicate(3, replicate(5, list( list( list( 1:3, 1:5), list( 1:3,  1:5))), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)
```